# currently which app is being used by iphone user

Tags: ios, iphone, background, activity-monitor

In my app, Can I check that which app is being used by a user right now, while my app is running in background?
If so, Is there any API available to get that info?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Makes no sense. The user can only be using the foreground app.

Comment: Hey, I wanted to know which app is in foreground now? do you think that makes no sense?

Comment: Your edited question makes a lot more sense than the original.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** There's no public API that lets you a background app find out about the foreground app, or get a list of running apps, or anything like that.

The only mechanism for finding out about other apps on the device is `+[UIApplication canOpenURL:]`, which you can use in some cases to find out whether a specific custom URL scheme can be handled. From that you can often guess that a particular app is installed, although the method really only tells you that *some* app that can handle the given scheme is installed. However, you still can't find out if that app is the foreground app, or even if it's running at all.